# Proper way to extract user information with Passport node.js and Socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, passport.js

I am using passport to login and authenticate the user as follows

**passport.js**

```
module.exports = function(passport){
  passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
      done(null, user.email);
  });

  passport.deserializeUser(function(email, done) {
      User.getUserByEmail(email, function(err, user) {
        done(err, user);
      });
  });
```

In my **app.js**

```
app.io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('a user connected');
    var userEmail = socket.request.session.passport.user;
    socket.username = userEmail;
```

Now I know that req.user will be populated with all the user info but I want  to extract user.description information in my app.io.sockets.on('connection') code just like I do with email. However, email is the only thing that is passed.

So I was thinking either
a) I should change my passport.js

```
 passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
      done(null, user);
  });
```

So it returns the whole user object to socket.request.session.passport.user; which seems insecure (Since password hash and everything else will be passed) (Unless there is a way I can pass user.email and user.description to done() without a whole object?

or 
b) Do a findOne look up in app.io.sockets.on('connection') using the user's email

Which is the right solution or is there a better way to extract one specific user field which is not an email/id.

**EDIT 1 UPDATE:**

passport.js local-login strategy

```
 // Login
  passport.use('local-login', new LocalStrategy({
    // changing default username field to email
    usernameField: 'email',
    passReqToCallback: true
  },
  ....
```

socket.request.session.passport variable looks like this

```
Session {
  cookie:
   { path: '/',
     _expires: null,
     originalMaxAge: null,
     httpOnly: true },
  flash: {},
  passport: { user: 'myemail@gmail.com' } }
```

**EDIT 2 UPDATE:**

Ok I think I figured out a better way is to do this in my app.js

```
// and user description to pass into our socket session
app.use(function(req, res, next){
  if (req.user){
   req.session.description = req.user.description;
  }
  next();
});
```

that way it will show up as follows

```
Session {
  cookie:
   { path: '/',
     _expires: null,
     originalMaxAge: null,
     httpOnly: true },
  flash: {},
  passport: { user: 'email@gmail.com' },
  description: 'Random Description' }
```

Comment: `sockets`, on a programming level, are not `socket.io` related... I removed the tag. See the [tag:sockets] tag details for more information.

Answer (score 0):

```
   module.exports = function(passport){
  passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    var object = user.email + ':'+ user.description
      done(null, object);
  });

  passport.deserializeUser(function(object, done) {

  var serial = object.split(':'),
      email  = serial[0]

      User.getUserByEmail(email, function(err, user) {
        done(err, user);
      });
  });
```

in the App.js

```
    app.io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('a user connected');
    var userObject = socket.request.session.passport.user.split(':');
    socket.username = userObject[0];
    socket.userDescription = userObject[1];
```

this way you'll save a roundtrip to the database.

ps: this is just an example and it's not tested nor validated which i'll highly recommend

hope this helps !

Comment: socket.request.session.passport.user only contains email account.. I am trying to figure out how to add another description field to it